# Using InternalsVisibleTo to test a private member

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have the following code, that I'm trying to Unit test:

```
class ConfigFile
{

    private XmlDocument configData;

    public ConfigFile()
    {
        configData = new XmlDocument();
    }

    public void loadConfigFile(string filename) 
    {
    }
}
```

the loadConfigFile method is void, so I need to check the configData field to verify that the data in there is correct.
To Do this, I'm trying to use the InternalsVisibleTo attribute - I've signed the unit test DLL, and generated the Public Key, so I now have:

```
    [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("ConfigTests, PublicKey=<PUBLICKEYVALUE>")]
    private XmlDocument configData;
```

The unit test still doesnt want to access the private field:

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void LoadConfigFileTest()
    {
        ConfigFile target = new ConfigFile();
        string filename = @"Config.xml";
        target.loadConfigFile(filename);
        Assert.AreEqual("<config></config>",target.configData.OuterXml);  
    }
```

At the Assert.AreEqual("",target.configData.OuterXml); line, I get the following error:

'ConfigTests.ConfigFile' does not contain a definition for 'configData' and no extension method 'configData' accepting a first argument of type 'ConfigTests.ConfigFile' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I though the InternalsVisibleTo attribute is supposed to allow Unit tests to access a private field... or am I missing something?

Comment: `InternalsVisibleTo` as its name suggests only alows access to things marked `internal`, it has no effect on private/protected members.

Comment: No, it allows you to get at another DLLs `internal` members, not another DLLs privates ;-)

Comment: OK... so I suppose the question becomes how do test that configData has a correct value? It should remain private as I dont want a developer to modify the value directly.

Answer (score 5):

InternalsVisibleTo enables you to access internal members (not private) from another assembly.

If you want to test a private method, then you should ask yourself if that method should be really private ?

Why do you want to test a private method ?  Doesn't it make more sense to test the public method that calls the private method ?  With your private method, you're hiding some implementation details and typically, that's something you don't want / need to test directly.  You want to test if your public 'contracts' work as expected. So, if everything is OK, you'll test your private method indirectly by testing the public method that uses / calls the private method.

Comment: I can only disagree with this. Private and internal both exist for their own reasons and both have different use cases. For example: you have a property with a backing field and you want to do some processing in the setter, exposing the backing field internally allows to set the value directly. Might be useful for testing purposes but NOT might be confusing later when working on the code (you might accidentally use the field instead of the property). Testing is a kind of special case though, so to "expose" private types or members internally only for testing is generally a bad idea imho.

Comment: I agree with this statement from @Mark.  He makes a great point in particular when doing complicated math or financial calculations with multiple dependent stages.

Breaking up the testing gives you a few advantages:

* Testing each stage allows catching the error at a lower level
* Testing each stage allows for fewer test cases


Image 5 inputs with 5 stages, the number of test cases can become huge.  By breaking it down you can reduce the test cases dramatically.

Comment: I'm nowhere saying that you should change the access modifier.  I'm saying that you should wonder if makes sense to test the private method itself / directly.  I mean that you should test the public method that calls the private one and you should reflect if it even makes sense to want to test the private one.   But, as I read my answer again, it might indeed be mis-interpreted.  I'll change my wording

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @FrederikGheysels. I understand your point and I think there's something to say for both points of view. Yes, logically it makes more sense to test the public API to see what works and what doest; I think this is something that should be done no matter what. However, the private members that support the public ones have their own behavior that might need testing as well. What if a private method doesn't behave exactly how it should? How can the public API be reliable if the foundation isn't? Or, as Blake states, what if you want to test many different situations?

Answer (score 3):

`InternalsVisibleTo` makes all `internal` children visible to the given assembly.

If you want to make a `private` method visible to another assembly that's essentially a paradox. It means breaking the foundations of OOD.

Unit testing is supposed to test the **public API** of a black box. i.e. your classes should be designed in such way that you **only** need to test their public methods.

1. Make your method `public`.
2. If it **mustn't** be `public`, then you can make it `protected internal` so that it can be accessible by using `InternalsVisibleTo`
3. Making it `protected internal` poses a security threat which must be addressed either by sealing the class and all its container classes or by standard security assessment.

If this didn't help, don't test it because it's not a concern for unit tests. Test a public method which uses this.

> If something is private, it literally (in every programming or spoken language) means no one else cares about it!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your class ConfigFile has other public properties/methods intended for reading the config values. For this reason the `configData` is private. In such case you can apply a black box tests to it (i.e. make assertions on these values rather than on entire XmlDocument)

Answer (score 0):

Change the access to internal protected and then seal the class.  This way ONLY the friend assembly can access it.

Comment: "This way ONLY the friend assembly can access it." Not true, see [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected-internal) on `protected internal`: The type or member can be accessed by any code in the assembly in which it is declared, OR from within a derived class in another assembly. Making it `protected internal` will still make the member visible to anything in the same assembly.